# using of append function

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtTSd.jpg) how to resolve it

data frame has no attribute then how to add elements in the dataframe in pandas library in jupyter notebook.And how to overcome the attribute error in the data frame in pandas library

Comment: In the future, please don't post screenshots. Or at least not screenshots alone. See the last bullet point **highlighted in bold** under 'Help others reproduce the problem' in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  (Side note: You mention Jupyter Notebooks, but they run a lot of language kernels and so for looking for advice usually best to focus on language, like say "add elements in the dataframe in pandas library in Python" and just mention Jupyter in case pertinent. It will help you researching the issue yourself, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Append was deprecated, use pandas concat instead.

```
df11 = pd.concat([df3, d], ignore_index=True)
```